# Testing web app client-side: what if server response format changed?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, web, tdd

I've just recently started to write tests for a web app I'm working on. And I've realised that I will have a lot of problems with my unit tests if a data, with which server responds, will change. Because all response data is mocked in app client-side tests, the tests should pass.

According [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) I should write tests first and only after that change the code.

Well, if I could quickly change all mocked data in my tests according to new data format, then it would be fine (I could see where tests fails). But what if I cannot do it quickly, what if there are many places where I need to do that and I just don't know where to look at?

**So here is my question:** is this problem comes down to the fact that I need to write tests in such a way as to be able easily change (or check) mocked data format in all of my tests? Or there are other solutions on that?

Comment: _what if there are many places where I need to do that and I just don't know where to look at?_ If you have that problem with just your unit tests, how are you going to be able to update the actual code successfully?

Comment: @bejado So it is bad if I can't easily change my mocked data format, right? In order to see what tests will fail.

Comment: You should be able to change your mocked data format relatively easily. See what tests fail, and make a plan to update your actual code which in turn fixes the tests.

Comment: @bejado Don't you want to express your suggestion in an answer post?